# Need help writing a BMI calculator in C

Tags: c

I am attempting to write a program that will take a user's input of weight and height and then return a BMI value and tell the user if they are under/over or normal weight. The code compiles with no errors, however no matter what numbers I input for weight and height, the result is always "You have a BMI of 0 and your weight status is overweight". Is there something wrong with my code or is my math just incorrect?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double wt_lb, ht_in, bmi, ht_ft;

    printf("Please enter your weight in whole pounds: ");
    scanf("%lf", &wt_lb);
    printf("Please enter your height in whole inches: ");
    scanf("%lf", &ht_in);

    ht_ft = ht_in/12;
    bmi = (703*wt_lb)/(ht_ft*ht_ft);

    if (bmi < 18.5) {
            printf("You have a BMI of %.lf, and your weight status is underweight\n" &bmi);
    } else if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi < 25) {
        printf("You have a BMI of %.lf, and your weight status is normal\n", &bmi);
    } else {
        printf("You have a BMI of %.lf, and your weight status is overweight\n", &bmi);
    }
}
```

Comment: You must never ignore the return value of an input operation. Without error checking, your program is essentially defective and undiagnosable.

Comment: Print out your wt_lb and ht_in values.

Comment: Are you really missing a comma in `printf("[...] underweight\n" &bmi);`?

Comment: You don't need this in your else if `bmi >= 18.5 &&`

Comment: Is the thing after the dot here `%.lf` supposed to be a one, or a lower case L? This looks like a weird format specifier if it's the latter.

Comment: Always when dividing by literals use float values. It should be `ht_ft = ht_in/12.f;`

Comment: @BrunoPhilipe: Dividing by an integral value is fine if the other operand is a floating point type, which it is here.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths; Good point. First I thought it was `1` but it is `l`. o.O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `&` from aal of your `printf`'s argument.

```
 printf("You have a BMI of %f, and your weight status is underweight\n" &bmi);  
                                                                        ^
                                                                        |
                                                                  Remove this &
```

It should be

```
  printf("You have a BMI of %f, and your weight status is underweight\n", bmi);
```

Also never use `%lf` specifier for `double` in `printf` (in `scanf` you have to use) instead use `%f`.

Answer (score 1):

In the printf statement don't use  &bmi, use simple bmi.
It should work